# Excel VBA for Filtering a Report Page on a Pivot

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot

I have a pivot table with two report page filters at the top. One is a string-based filter (4 options of universes to select from) and one is date-based (one entry per month, so 09/01/2018 and 08/01/2018 going back 5 years). I’m trying to use VBA to update the date filter to select, say, the most recent 3 months.

I’ve tried everything. The .PivotItems approaches don’t work for the report filter with dates. It works perfectly if I try it with the universe filter right above it but says it can’t access the PivotItems method of the PivotFields class when I switch the code to the other filter, so it must be due to the fact they’re dates.

I can clear all filters on my date filter just fine, and I can use .CurrentPage to set the filter to a single value - say, 09/01/2018 - but I can’t use these methods to deselect everything and select a few specific months.

I used the macro recorder as a last resort and it saves it using the .PivotItems method to change the filter, but if I run that exact macro it saved it throws the same error that it can’t acces PivotItems.

I’m at wits end. Does the fact the filter uses dates change the way I have to acces it with VBA? And how on earth do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions of connecting Slicers to Pivot Tables (or even multiple Pivot tables):

https://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/how-to-insert-slicers-into-an-excel-pivot-table/

https://exceljet.net/lessons/how-to-use-a-slicer-with-multiple-pivot-tables

https://excelchamps.com/blog/link-slicer-to-multiple-pivot-tables/

Follow the instructions, and please note that you don't need VBA code

Comment: Yeah, not really what I’m looking to do. I have dozens of pivots per tab across 20 tabs that update each month. I need some to have their filters adjust to the most recent 3 months, some adjust to select months YTD, some to select rolling 12 months, etc. Rather than have the user scroll through and select each and potentially miss one, I want to automate the selection, as described. It works perfectly for any field used in the report filter except for the field that has dates in it. The rest of the code makes it so the entire workbook updates itself and spits to PPT formatted. Thanks though.

Comment: @boldneur0n - which way are the dates defined? because if you need "last 3 months" and "rolling 12 months" you need to define a date dimension: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/06/26/automatically-generating-date-dimension-tables-in-excel-2016-power-pivot/